# Building NSIS from source on windows (VS2012)

Tags: nsis, scons

I'm working on a pure x64 version of my software.  Our installer for the x86 version is NSIS and my software is built using VS2012.  I found online that in order to build x64 installers using NSIS you have to build NSIS (and all plugins/etc) from source.  That is the end goal.  However, right now I'm having issues just building x86 (before moving on to x64) using the instructions in the NSIS docs.  https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/AppendixG.html#build_windows

I'm trying to build NSIS v3.0.4 which uses SCons to build.  I've installed scons using pip (SCons version 3.1.1).

However, when trying to build NSIS, I get the following (using python 3.8.0).

```
C:\Source\nsis\nsis-code-r7069-NSIS-tags-v304>scons ZLIB_W32=C:\Source\zlib-1.2.7 MSTOOLKIT=yes
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object:
  File "C:\Source\nsis\nsis-code-r7069-NSIS-tags-v304\SConstruct", line 263:
    for v in re.compile(r'^\\H\{[v]?(\S+)\}', re.M).finditer(File('#/Docs/src/history.but').get_contents()): # Try to parse the Halibut history file
```

the section of the SConstruct file is as follows (starting at line 260 so the for loop starts at 263):

```
if not defenv.has_key('VER_PACKED'):
    import re
    found = None
    for v in re.compile(r'^\\H\{[v]?(\S+)\}', re.M).finditer(File('#/Docs/src/history.but').get_contents()): # Try to parse the Halibut history file
        if v and not found:
            v = v.group(1).split('.')
            if len(v) >= 2:
                mi = int(re.search(r'\d+', v[1]).group())
                if mi < 1: mi = 1 # Make sure we can subtract 1 from the minor number so trunk stays below the next release
                defenv['VER_PACKED'] = '0x%0.2i%0.3i%0.2i%0.1i' % (int(re.search(r'\d+', v[0]).group()), mi - 1, 66, 6)
                if int(defenv['VER_PACKED'], 0) >= int('0x03000000', 0):
                    found = v
    if not found:
        defenv['VER_PACKED'] = '0x%0.2i%0.3i%0.2i%0.1i' % (3, 3, 42, 0) # Default to a version number we never used
    print('WARNING: VER_PACKED not set, defaulting to %s!' % defenv['VER_PACKED'])
```

At this point, I'm not sure if there is a dependency I'm missing or if this is an issue with the build script and needs to be reported at the NSIS issue tracker.  Ideas?

-UPDATE 1-

Based on suggestions from @Anders, first I tried to build the head of the repo (r7132 trunk) instead of v3.0.4 using Python3.  This got me farther but still failed on what appears to be Python2 vs 3 syntax errors in mstoolkit.py (might be a symptom of another issue rather than the cause though).  I didn't investigate this too much further yet.

So next, I went back to Python 2.7.  This got me further but the mstoolkit.py appears to be dependent on VS2003 implementation.  I duplicated the VCToolkitInstallDir environment variable on my machine using the contents of the VS110COMNTOOLS (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools) but that fails also:

```
  File "C:\Source\IQClient_Interim\Shared\third_party\nsis\nsis-code-r7132-NSIS-tags-v304\SCons\Tools\mstoolkit.py", line 87, in get_msvctoolkit_paths
    raise SCons.Errors.InternalError, "The Platform SDK directory was not found in the registry or in the `MSSdk` environment variable."
InternalError: The Platform SDK directory was not found in the registry or in the `MSSdk` environment variable.
```

I don't know what the VS2003 VCToolkitInstallDir ENVVAR was pointing to to fix this.

With all that said, I just noticed that Anders said that I might also have to use an older version of scons as well with python2.7 so I suppose I'll spend some time investigating that (along with looking into @bdbaddog's solution).

-UPDATE 2-
it was the mstoolkit directive (see @Anders answer's comments)
I got it working after that while using py 2.7 for NSIS 3.0.4.

Now on to x64 build but that's a different story so I'll post a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSIS v3.04 does not support Python 3, you have to grab the [latest source code from SVN](https://sourceforge.net/p/nsis/code/HEAD/tree/). v3.05 is coming out soon with support for Python 3.

VS2012 is old enough that you should be able to use Python 2.7 and a older version of SCons as an alternative.

As a final alternative, you can try to apply [this diff](https://sourceforge.net/p/nsis/code/7124/) to v3.04.

Comment: Tried both of these now.  First tried building from your link but it looks like the mstoolkit.py hasn't been updated for Python3 yet. So I went back to python 2.7 but now it fails to find the VS toolkit.  I tried to dummy the VSToolkitInstallDir ENVVAR it  is looking for using the VS110COMNTOOLS envvar that exists from VS2012 but it didn't work.  Looks like the mstoolkit.py is very dependent on VS2003.  Ideas?  Or should I simply look for other alternatives than VS to build this (keeping in mind that x64 is my final goal).  Updating the OP currently.

Comment: Why are you using mstoolkit.py? The mstoolkit option is for the old free express versions, scons should be able to pick up your normal VS install if you don't specify mstoolkit=yes. That being said, that .py file is probably the only one that has not been updated for python3 and if you fix it I'll accept a patch.

Comment: I just came to the same conclusion about 20mins ago after reading through the scons docs a bit.  As a windows dev, I've been trained to automatically search out anything that says MS when dealing with open source projects so I was expecting it to not work without specifying to use a microsoft toolkit.  Oops!  It's now humming along nicely.  Assuming this works, any quick pointers on where to go from here to build x64?  Is there any docs for this yet?

Comment: As far as NSIS is concerned, you just need to set the target_arch scons parameter to amd64. You obviously need a scons and 64-bit compiler configuration that actually works. 32-bit NSIS installers can install 64-bit programs (except on server core or other places where wow64 has been removed).

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're running into is twofold.

1. Python > 3.0 strings are no longer bytes. They are unicode
2. SCons which supports Python > 3.0 (SCons >3.0 supports Python 2.7 and Python > 3.5.0)

In order to support this Node()'s (SCons's way of representing files, directories, and values which feed into a build) now have two methods get_contents() and get_text_contents().

Since you're using Python 3.8.0, get_contents() will return bytes, which explains the error you've received.

The proper way to resolve it is to change this line:

```
for v in re.compile(r'^\\H\{[v]?(\S+)\}', re.M).finditer(File('#/Docs/src/history.but').get_contents()): # Try to parse the Halibut history file
```

to:

```
for v in re.compile(r'^\\H\{[v]?(\S+)\}', re.M).finditer(File('#/Docs/src/history.but').get_text_contents()): # Try to parse the Halibut history file
```

Please let me know if this doesn't resolve the issue.
Also, if you're willing to install Python 2.7 and reinstall SCons via

```
py -2.7 -mpip install scons
```

(Assuming you've install the py launcher when installing Python. Not sure if that's default with Python 3.8 and/or Python 2.7.  If not then /python -m pip install scons.  You might have to install pip as well. Once again not sure on the default for that.)

Then you can avoid changing the SConstruct file.

Hope this helps!